# How to disable password prompt while mounting partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, policykit

I'm using ubuntu mini.iso to setup a dual boot system. I've already installed `polkit` to be able to mount windows(and other ntfs partitions) while using GUI. But every time I try to mount them from file manager(Thunar) after a restart, I get a password prompt. I've tried adding following rules to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-mount-partitions.rules`:

```
// Password-less mounting of local partitions
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system" && subject.isInGroup("sudo")) {
       return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

But this is not working.How can I disable it?

Comment: Those who stumbled on this page while trying to disable password prompt in MX Linux, can use a simple switch in MX Tweaks to disable it(It takes care of setting the rules).For details check https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/mount-internal-partition-without-using-root-password/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20gvfs%2Fudisks2,utilize%20gvfs%20and%2For%20udisks2.

Comment: In my case using the mxlinux image I discovered that the user was "demo" and the same word was the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2 days found a solution from [fedora website](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/49260/disable-entering-root-password-everytime-while-mounting-on-fedora-20/). Here's what I did:
`sudo vi /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-mount-without-password.pkla`
Entered the following lines of code into it:

```
[storage group mount override]
Identity=unix-user:USERNAME
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

And replaced USERNAME my username.
Now, I don't need to enter password during mounting from thunar.
Edit : for beginners `gnome-disk-utility` is a good tool to manage `/etc/fstab` . To enable auto mount of a drive at startup open the disk app, select the partition,select 'additional partition options', select 'edit mount options' , disable 'User session Defaults' , tick 'mount at system startup' and enter your password to allow changes.
Note: Users facing same problem please consider using @M K 's solution of automounting all drives at stratup. It can be done by editing `/etc/fstab` using any editor or you can use `gnome-disk-utility` if you like to achieve same result with gui. In my case I wanted an answer specific to polkit due to reasons mentioned in the comments section of his answer. So choose a suitable method depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I would disregard any workaround and add a permanent mount entry into `/etc/fstab`.

Try `man fstab` for reference.

There are no definitive steps to doing a very specific mount. Each case comes with its variables. Anyway, running *Terminal*:

- Run `df -h` and examine the output to know the block device address of your Windows partitions.
- Edit `/etc/fstab` as super-user (e. g. using GEdit) and add entries for each Windows partition, like:

  ```
  /dev/sdb2   /my_mount_point_folder  ntfs    rw  0   0
  ```

This will mount block device `/dev/sdb2` at folder `/my_mount_point_folder` with read-write permissions. This happens with every boot, automatically.

That should do it. It is still good to review `fstab` manual: in *Terminal* run `man fstab`.

Comment: Can you help me with that? Some hints or may be some examples would be great.

Comment: @AbinashDash Just edited my answer on your request.

Comment: Kernel device names aren't all that predictable and not ideal in `fstab`. It's better to use file system labels or UUIDs. See [How do I correctly mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](/q/113733/175814) for details and other useful NTFS mount options.

Comment: What if i don't want to mount them at boot time? Sometimes when windows doesn't shutdown correctly, mounting the windows partition(C drive) gives error while mounting and I'll have to mount that drive manully anyway. So plz consider giving a solutions with `polkit`.

Comment: @AbinashDash Please note that this is meant by design; Linux security. The only way to bypass this is either run a `root` session (very dangerous), or if you really trust `polkit` (which I know nothing about) find a way to run it (i.e `polkit`) as `root` (which is as equally dangerous).

Comment: Okay. I can disable auto mount on startup by `noauto` option, I guess. Still waiting for someone to provide solution using `polkit`.

Comment: I'm using these options `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,noauto,user,uid=1000,gid=1000` as mount options. still I get a password prompt. Any errors in my options?

Comment: @AbinashDash: Your edit suggestions makes for the seed of a great new answer or an addition to your own. :-)

Comment: Okay . I'll add that to my answer then. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: On fedora 31, I run `df -Th` then edited `/etc/fstab` by adding `/file/system/ mounted/on type defaults 0 0` (e.g. `/dev/sdb /run/media/username/data                    ext4    defaults        0 0`)